# How to provide symmetrical power supply with laboratory power supply?

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier

I am making a circuit with operational amplifier. I want to provide symmetrical supply, -12 V and +12 V, because I need differential amplifier, to obtain both positive and negative output voltages.

I wonder, how to provide such supply with laboratory power supply. I have 3 sockets: +, -, and GND. How should I make connections between those sockets to obtain symmetrical supply?

[image: Example laboratory power supply]

Answer (score 4):

- Leave Green disconnected.
- Pick a red as your positive.
- Connect its black to the other red.
- Use the other black as your negative.
- The red/black junction is zero.
- Enable the tracking function so your controls affect both outputs at once.

Per request for additional information about tracking function, when you've got a dual supply, and the tracking function is active, it makes the controls affect both outputs "symmetrically", so you don't have to dial them in independently. One output is designated as the master, and the other output is slaved-to (i.e. tracks) the master output.

Comment: Also a good idea to check the manual for your  specific supply.

Comment: If it's a professional isolated power supply as shown you can connect the ground (Green) to any point you like.

Comment: @vicatcu, can you write some more about tracking function?

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do really is look at it in schematic form:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxhhVc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This is consistent with my original answer. I am pretty sure it's important to leave the supplies isolated (greens not connected)

Comment: Whether to connect the midpoint to ground (green) depends on context :  it's often a very good idea to do so. But sometimes you need to isolate your system (e.g. because something you're connecting it to has its own ground connection and you want to avoid a ground loop)

Comment: It is worth noting that the green ground on the front is actual mains earth, the supply chassis.

Answer (score 0):

You can also  use single polarity supply voltage of 24 volts in a capacitor coupled circuit. To make the voltages equal i.e., +_12V use voltage divider circuit along with the main circuit! This is an alternative option if you are giving only one DC supply voltage.